# Parsing camera frames in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, xamarin, maui

I want to make real-time .NET MAUI app powered by object detection model. In .NET MAUI I can use Media Picker but it only opens camera app and take the photo/video. I want to use camera all the time and I'll draw bounding boxes from model. I can handle this situation in Windows platform by using Emgu.Cv library. However it's not free in .NET MAUI. I just need to parse camera frames and send it to my AI model. How can I do it?

I tried to use OpenCvSharp.Android library. It is designed for Xamarin but it didn't work. I couldn't find library for .NET MAUI. Also, there is CameraView for Xamarin but is it what I want, I don't sure.

Comment: you would likely need to use the native camera API for each platform to do this

Comment: For inspiration you could take a look at how ZXing.NET.MAUI does this for QR code scanning: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/tree/main/ZXing.Net.MAUI/Platforms the worst part is the handlers you need to implement, which is a bootstrapping nightmare in its own

Comment: Here is link: https://github.com/dotnet/maui

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Savi.Maui.CameraTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Savi.Maui.CameraTools/0.1.4-preview2) I found a camera tools package from nuget. It provides CameraView, CardScannerView, and BarcodeScannerView but it didn't work. @Cheesebaron If I find camera view for MAUI can I complete my purpose? Thanks for the other answers. I'll consider native camera API also.

Comment: The last one you are linking to, you could use the FrameReady event. It is the same code as in ZXing.NET.MAUI. The author didn't properly attribute his code with the proper license that the ZXing package uses.

Comment: This might be help, [Manual Camera Controls in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/intro-to-manual-camera-controls).

Comment: What about using [Camera.MAUI](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI/tree/d9ee42a428b9ee41efff624fe01643b62c7781e6)? It allows you to drop a camera preview onto your xaml page and bind to the SnapShotStream using a `Stream` property in your ViewModel. Gerard Versluis recently did a tutorial on it (mentioning MS are working on their own version). For object detection, I've just found [ML.NET Model Builder](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/object-detection-ml-dotnet-model-builder/). I'm not sure yet if it meets my needs but I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Probably new libraries are released in one year. It was for my graduation project and I did it with Kotlin + Tensorflow but I'll try to make it in .NET MAUI also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a QR code scanner for **Windows**, **Android** and **iOS** using .NET MAUI. You can refer to my sample code: https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/tree/main/example/maui

[image]

### How to get camera frames?

- [Windows](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/blob/main/example/maui/DesktopCameraPage.xaml.cs): Use `OpenCvSharp` to get camera frames.

  ```cs
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    capture.Read(mat);
  ```
- [Android](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/blob/main/example/maui/Platforms/Android/CameraPreviewRenderer.cs) and [iOS](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/blob/main/example/maui/Platforms/iOS/CameraPreviewRenderer.cs): Create a custom camera preview class with platform-specific code.

  **Android**

  ```cs
  public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){}
  ```

  **iOS**

  ```cs
    public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer(AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection){}
  ```